# Monodroid DensityDpi to Int

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to convert DensityDpi to Int. I tried like this:

```
int dens = dm.DensityDpi;
```

and of curse it doesn't work. The complete code is:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.WidthPixels;
int height = dm.HeightPixels;
int dens = dm.DensityDpi;
double wi = (double)width / (double)dens;
double hi = (double)height/(double)dens;
double x = Math.Pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.Pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x+y);
```

I'm trying to find the inch of screen.

Considering that there show that constants are int I don't know why it doesn't work.
( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html )
I think that are same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android:

```
var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);

private const float INCH = 25.4f;

var ydpi = metrics.Ydpi; // dpi in vertical direction
var xdpi = metric.Xdpi; // dpi in horizontal direction
var pHeight = metrics.HeightPixels; // total pixels in vertical direction
var pWidth = metrics.WidthPixels; // total pixels in horizontal direction
var iHeight = (pHeight / ydpi); // screenheight in inches
var iWidth = (pWidth / xdpi); // screenwidth in inches
var mHeight = (pHeight / ydpi) * INCH; // screenheight in millimeters
var mWidth = (pWidth / xdpi) * INCH; // screenwidth in millimeters
```

Afaik there is no way to query an iOS-device directly about it's DPI.

You can however calculate it using some constants. iPhone's are 163 ppi and iPhone Retina's are exactly double that.

```
private const float INCH = 25.4f;

var ppi = 163 * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale; // pixels per inch for an iPhone or iPhone Retina
var ppmm = ppi / INCH;                // pixels per millimeter
var pHeight = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Height; // screen height in pixels
var pWidth =  UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Width; // screen width in pixels
var iHeight =  (pHeight / ppi); // screen height in millimeters
var iWidth =   (pWidth / ppi); // screen height in millimeters
var mHeight = (pHeight / ppi) * INCH; // screen height in millimeters
var mWidth =  (pWidth / ppi) * INCH; // screen height in millimeters
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented abstraction over the display properties in Xamarin.Forms.Labs project. Although it is targeting Xamarin.Forms it can also be used without it. For Android and WP8 the properties are calculated but for iOS they are determined by the hardware version of the device. You can install the packages from NuGet (Xamarin.Forms.Labs) for each platform (iOS, Android, WP8) to get a fully functional, tested and easy to use classes.

Here is link for the full source code for the Android display:

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Droid/Device/Display.cs

```
    public Display()
    {
        var dm = Metrics;
        this.Height = dm.HeightPixels;
        this.Width = dm.WidthPixels;
        this.Xdpi = dm.Xdpi;
        this.Ydpi = dm.Ydpi;

        this.FontManager = new FontManager(this);
    }

    public static Android.Util.DisplayMetrics Metrics
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        }
    }
```

The physical size is calculated with extension methods (so they can be reused by all platforms) based on the display density:

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Device/DisplayExtensions.cs

```
    public static double ScreenSizeInches(this IDisplay screen)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(screen.ScreenWidthInches(), 2) + Math.Pow(screen.ScreenHeightInches(), 2));
    }

    public static double ScreenWidthInches(this IDisplay screen)
    {
        return screen.Width / screen.Xdpi;
    }

    public static double ScreenHeightInches(this IDisplay screen)
    {
        return screen.Height / screen.Ydpi;
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the Android info:

[image]

Also available for iOS & WP8:

[image]
[image]